# With Python and SQLite, how do i return the last n item inside the database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, loops

I have a database containing a list of status updates and time stamp.

by executing the following python script

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys


    con = lite.connect('Status.db')

    with con:    

        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Status")
        print "The Status database now contains:"

        for row in cur:
            print row
```

results in the output:

```
The Status database now contains:
(1333155451.8815, u'message')
(1333155469.205055, u'message1')
(1333155473.496727, u'message2')
```

However, as the database grows, i wish to only view the latest, say, 10 messages. With the option of viewing older messages.

Could anyone give me some tips on how i would go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, aod use the `DESC` keyword to show in reverse timestamp order:

```
SELECT * FROM <yourtable> ORDER BY <timestampcol> DESC LIMIT 10
```

(For future reference: When you're asking about how to query your data, you should post information about your schema, like table names, column names, and datatypes. It makes it much easier to post an answer containing the actual query.)

Comment: That's much easier than what i was trying, which was doing something with for loops and while loops. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Look at ORDER BY and LIMIT clausuls. Those should do the trick :)